# javascript element.className error?

Tags: javascript, classname

I am trying to get the body's classname to use in an if/else statement in plain javascript.

To my surprise the `element.className` trows me errors everytime:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined*

```js
 alert( document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className.match("home") );
 alert( document.getElementById("container").className.match("fooclass") );
```

```html
<body class="home page">
 <div id="container" class="fooclass"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you try after putting your code in document.onload event?

Comment: Because here you script tags are appended after the elements

Comment: As @gurvinder372 suggests, this probably gets caused by the DOM not having rendered yet.

Comment: Put your javascript code right before `</body>`

Comment: Can't you use `document.body`? Or is it better practice to use  `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` instead?

Comment: yes! That's it!! I understand now. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function(){

    alert( document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className.match("home") );
    alert( document.getElementById("container").className.match("fooclass") );

}
```

You can put this anywhere on the page ;)